# How to stop loadbalancer's re-invoke function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have lambda's and `ecs`

`lambda` controls start/stop the ecs.

However when stopping the ecs with `stop_task`, it is revoked immediately by `LoadaBalancer`

I should stop the `LoadBalancer` at the same time with `stop_task`

Or is there any way to stop the only `LoadBalancer`'s re-invoke function?

For example stop is like this,

```
import json
import boto3

ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    temp = ecs.list_tasks(
        cluster='ss-dev-cluster'
    )
    for t in temp['taskArns']:
    
        response = ecs.stop_task(
            cluster='ss-dev-cluster',
            task=t
        )
    
        print(response)
        '''
        failures = response['failures']
        if len(failures) != 0:
            print(failures)
            return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': json.dumps('NG!')
            }
        '''
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('OK!')
    }
```

---

**Solved**

Thanks to @MarkB

I use `update_service` to change the `desiredCount` of `Fargate` instead of `run_task` and `stop_task`

These are my lambda code

```
import json
import boto3
import os

ecs = boto3.client('ecs')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    response = ecs.update_service(
        cluster=os.environ['cluster'],
        desiredCount=1,
        service=os.environ['service'],
    )
```

Comment: The ECS here is EC2 or Fargate? What do you mean "it is revoked immediately by LoadaBalancer"?

Comment: ECS is `Fargate` Loadabalancer always health checking the container and restart it automatically, when it stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running a load balanced application, you are not just running an ECS task, you are running an ECS service. When running an ECS service you should never be calling `run_task` or `stop_task` directly. You should be setting the desired count of the ECS service and letting the ECS service control the stopping/starting of tasks. It is the ECS service that keeps recreating the task after you stop it, not the load balancer. The ECS service also controls the registration/deregistration of the tasks with the load balancer.

Comment: I see. thank you very!! I don't use `run_task` and `stop_task`. I change the `desired_count` of fargate , from lambda with boto3 `response = ecs.update_service(
        cluster=os.environ['cluster'],
        desiredCount=1, # when stopping ->0
        service=os.environ['service'],
    )` it works!!